# Как создать подтверждение удаление через Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

депс. У меня такой джунорский вопрос. Как через php(гет параметр) можно создать подтверждение удаление объекта через модальное окно?(fancybox 3 использую)
Спасибо за уделённое время.

Comment: А зачем здесь аякс? Запрашиваете подтверждение, потом отправляете аякс запрос на удаление

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "подтверждение удаления"? Что-то аля `if(confirm('удаляем?')){alert('Да');}` ?

Comment: @InDevX Есть две кнопки "да" и "нет" и выше их название объекта ля data.data[i].name

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да так я и хочу сделать, тока как это сделать))